# Buggy 400+ Characters Explanation/Link

Tags: bug, jobs

The section in the upper right corner of my profile states:

> Entered responsibilities for each experience entry (400+ characters)

This is unclear, confusing, and the link does not appear to work correctly.

- Why does the wording say *entered* (past tense)? Should it instead say that I *need* to enter responsibilities for each experience entry?
- Why does it say this when I have already entered responsibilities for each experience entry? Should it instead say that I need to make sure the responsibilities section is at least 400 characters for each experience entry?
- If it needs me to enter at least 400 characters, shouldn't it tell me how many characters I have for each item (both as I type, and when I'm not editing).
- Finally, the word *experience* in the paragraph described above is a link. But half the time I click it, it creates a *new* experience. This makes no sense. I already have seven experience entries going back to 1995. What does it want from me?

Comment: Trying to figure out this same thing.

Comment: I am stuck here too. It is really frustrating since it seems to be the one thing stopping me from getting a complete, unlocked, profile.

Comment: Same on my profile.

Comment: After most of a year, this is still unresolved...